# Setting up Emacs and SLIME to work with Kawa

Tags: emacs, slime

According to this site [here](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsScheme.html#sec22), it is possible to have SLIME work with Kawa Scheme. However, I cannot find any instructions anywhere on precisely how to do this. Even on this site, the link goes to an empty page.

I already have my SLIME working with SBCL, and would like to keep that if possible. How could I set up my SLIME to work with Kawa?